# Как парсить сайт, где есть пагинация и при переходе по страница не меняется url в строке браузера

Tags: python, ajax, xhr

Делаю парсер сайта на Python, но столкнулся с проблемой. Когда я нажимаю кнопку перехода на следующую станицу каталога, url никаким образом не изменяется. Прочитал в гугле и понял, что это реализовано через ajax-запросы (надеюсь не перепутал). Вопрос в том, как мне переходить на другие страницы сайта через url? Нашёл статью, в которой следуя инструкции я понял, что при нажатии кнопки перехода на следующую страницу, приходит XHR-запрос с словарём. Буду благодарен если кто-то хоть натолкнёт на мысль, как это реализовать. Спасибо

Comment: Так выполните точно такой же запрос и получите нужные данные =)

Comment: @Inventor Не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду. Дело в том, что url никак не изменяется, а соответственно не могу передать url другой страницы. Всё равно будет парситься первая страница, чей url я и обрабатываю. Получается так, что скрипт парсит 1-ую страницу, переходит на вторую (с помощью имитации нажатия кнопки на Selenium) но данные берёт по старому url, поэтому значения в консоли такие же. Вопрос в том, как сделать что бы скрипт при переходе на следующую страницу парсил её, а не прошлую по url'у

Comment: Не может такого быть, другой url/method/cookie/headers/formdata Иначе сервер возвращал бы тоже самое

Comment: @Inventor да, я понимаю. Но конкретно "видимый" url не изменяется. Я могу прикрепить ссылку https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Glock-18%20%7C%20High%20Beam%20%28Factory%20New%29. В том то и дело, что я не знаю как отслеживать тот "невидимый" текст, который идёт после url'а. При нажатии на кнопку перехода на некст страницу приходит xhr-запрос с словарём. Но я в этой теме не силён и понятия не имею как его обрабатывать. С этим мне и нужна помощь

Comment: Добавил ответ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загрузка контента происходит не только по `url`, который вы видите в адресной строке браузера, контент так же может загружаться с помощью [XHR](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest). Чтобы увидеть как именно это происходит откройте [инструменты разработчика](https://support.google.com/campaignmanager/answer/2828688?hl=ru) в браузере и перейдите во вкладку `Network`. Далее переходите по страницам и смотрите какие запросы и куда выполняются.

Посмотрим на пример из комментария к вопросу (`https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Glock-18%20%7C%20High%20Beam%20%28Factory%20New%29`).

Видно что получение контента на страницах происходит по адресу: `https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Glock-18%20%7C%20High%20Beam%20%28Factory%20New%29/render/?query=&start=0&count=10&country=RU&language=russian&currency=1`

В query запросе этого URL меняются параметры `start` и `count`, которые указывают с какого элемента начать и сколько элементов получить соответственно

Comment: да, я понимаю что приходит запрос, но как мне его использовать? Я имею ввиду как мне, к примеру, перейти на вторую страницу без нажатия на кнопку? Просто по тому url, который приходит в запросе я получаю словарь и не знаю как его обрабатывать. То есть я понимаю, что нужно изменить start на 10, так как именно такое значение он имеет при переходе на следующую страницу. Но как мне это использовать. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @IIIyTH1K используйте модуль `json` в python, чтобы распарсить данные, которые вам приходят, вы получите обычный питоновский словарь, оттуда берите то, что вы хотите

Comment: хорошо, а когда я получу данные словаря как мне их применить? Я просто с ajax никогда не работал. Мне нужно отправить запрос с указанием данных по типу start=10 и т.д.? Тогда как это сделать? Спасибо

Comment: @IIIyTH1K В ответе есть поле `results_html`. там представлен `html` код страницы, парсите его. Но я вам по секрету скажу, что есть ещё поле `listinginfo`, где представлены чистые данные, примерно это вы получите после парсинга

Comment: То есть я могу почти не взаимодействовать с самим сайтом, а просто в скрипте формировать запрос на url по типу `https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Glock-18%20|%20High%20Beam%20(Factory%20New) + /render/?query=&start= + *тут с помощью переменной выбираю необходимое число* +&count= + *тут тоже с помощью переменной выбираю необходимое число* +&country=RU&language=russian&currency=1`? Тогда ещё такой вопрос, а могу ли я каким-либо образом открыть в браузере, скажем, сразу 23 страницу? То есть возможно ли вообще перейти на необходимую страницу просто использовав url?

Comment: @IIIyTH1K в браузере не сможете, потому там их JS код так построен, что сначала 1 страница открывается, с помощью Python можете открывать любую страницу в любой момент

Comment: то есть в любом случае мне нужно будет вручную листать до необходимой страницы что б купить скин? Спасибо большое за помощь. Нужно будет почитать про xhr-запросы)

Comment: @IIIyTH1K нет, после того как у вас открылась первая страница вы можете переходить на любую

Comment: мне уже неудобно задавать вопросы) Каким образом я могу с помощью скрипта открыть сразу необходимую мне страницу? К примеру на странице 65 был найден необходимый мне скин. Я теперь могу открыть сразу же 65 страницу в браузере с помощью скрипта?

Comment: @IIIyTH1K Почему вы в браузере открываете я не понимаю? Вы хотите спарсить данне или что делаете?

Comment: скрипт сравнивает паттерны скинов на торговой площадке Стима с "базой данных", которая является словарём и находится в том же файле что и скрипт. Если найдено совпадение (паттерн скина присутствует в списке), то в консоль выводится сообщение о том, что совпадение найдено и указывается номер скина и страница. Соответственно если я хочу купить этот скин мне нужно в браузере открыть ту самую страницу на торговой площадке. И поэтому мне и интересно, можно ли открыть сразу, скажем 23 страницу (если скин был найден именно на ней), или мне нужно будет листать вручную. Как-то так)

Comment: @IIIyTH1K ну там снизу написаны номера страниц, тыкайте на нужную

Comment: но если нужна какая-нибудь 423 страница прийдётся вручную переходить? Я это имею ввиду

Comment: @IIIyTH1K в браузере, да